# bootstrap v4 navbar, body text shows above navbar onscroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I am working on my personal portfolio website using bootstrap v4 and my navbar is transparent and when i scroll over text, the body text blocks the view of the navbar text and doesn't allow me to click the navbar links, how can i fix this?

https://caromin.github.io/Caromin-WebPortfolio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's a problem about the css property `z-index`.Its specific definition and usage can be referred at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp .To fix your bug, try adding `z-index: 9999` to the css property of the `<nav></nav>`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the css

```
#navscroll {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fix. Please add following css

```
#navscroll {
z-index: 1;}
```

Cheers !